# Increment Number (variable) in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I need to increment a number inside a varaible in a bash script.
But after the script is done, the variable should be exported with the new number and available next time the script is running.

```
IN MY SHELL

    set x=0
```

---

```
SCRIPT

" If something is true.. do"
export x=$(($x+1)) //increment variable and save it for next time
if [ $x -eq 3 ];then 
    echo test
fi
exit
```

Comment: Persistent variables are called *files*. Save the state in a file and read it back. E.g. to save use `echo "$x" > myfile` and to load use `x=$(cat myfile)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot persist a variable in memory between two processes; the value needs to be stored somewhere and read on the next startup. The simplest way to do this is with a file. (The `fish` shell, which supports "universal" variables, uses a separate process that always runs to communicate with new shells as they start and exit. But even this "master" process needs to use a file to save the values when *it* exits.)

```
# Ensure that the value of x is written to the file
# no matter *how* the script exits (short of kill -9, anyway)
x_file=/some/special/file/somewhere
trap 'printf '%s\n' "$x" > "$x_file"' EXIT

x=$(cat "$x_file")   # bash can read the whole file with x=$(< "$x_file")
# For a simple number, you only need to run one line
# read x < "$x_file"
x=$((x+1))
if [ "$x" -eq 3 ]; then
   echo test
fi
exit
```

Answer (score 0):

Exporting a variable is one way only. The exported variable will have the correct value for all child processes of your shell, but when the child exits, the changed value is lost for the parent process. Actually, the parent process will only see the initial value of the variable.

Which is a good thing. Because **all** child processes can potentially change the value of an exported variable, potentially messing things up for the other child processes (if changing the value would be bi-directional).

You could do one of two things:

- Have the script save the value to a file before exiting, and
  reading it from the file when starting
- Use `source your-script.bash` or `. your-script.bash`. This way, your
  shell will not create a child process, and the variable gets changed in
  same process